# Integrating markdown into angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angularjs-directive, markdown

I've started writing a simple app using AngularJS + NodeJS to learn more about the stack, and it appears that getting markdown to work is a bit tricky and not that well supported. I'm coming from a ruby background, and I used the `redcarpet` markdown library, which was pretty standard and straightforward.

I've come across the [angular-markdown-directive](https://github.com/btford/angular-markdown-directive):

**Pros**

- Simple to setup
- Uses `ngSanitize` to clean user-submitted markdown. This library is supported by the official Angular team.

**Cons**

- It uses `showdown` under the hood, which seems to have died a while back, but small progress seems to be picking up with the new maintainer. However, it has quite a few outstanding bugs, two particular bug reports dating back to 2013 and 2014 are worrying:

  (1) Underscores are apparently interpreted to be italicized (will create malformed links):
  `https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown/issues/96`

  (2) Security issue that allows XSS still not patched:
  `https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown/issues/57`

I'm not sure if (2) will be an issue in my case, since `ngSanitize` may help.

There is another library called `markdown-it`, but this library handles markdown in Nodejs instead of Angular. But their examples doesn't say much about best security practices.

--

Are there any full examples on how markdown can be securely integrated into a Node/Angular app? `angular-markdown-directive` seems like a good fit but has some painful problems, and most other markdown libraries are either dying/dead or they gloss over security in a production environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use `markdown-it`. It's pretty flexible; it actually allows parsing from either server or the client so it's up to you how and where you'd like to parse the markdown.

For me, I've opted to save the markdown text in the database and then parse the markdown on the client, and it works very well.

As for security, `markdown-it` comes with some [built-in security measures](https://github.com/markdown-it/markdown-it/blob/master/docs/security.md), which is very nice. There is also a separate security module that you can use with it that offers additional features.